# What is wrong with this PSpice simulation?

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation

I am trying to simulate this circuit on PSpice as my first PSpice homework, I'm required to learn to simulate circuits on this software.

[image]

From calculations, we know that:

- Ix = 16 A.
- Current through 20 V source is 6 A.
- Voltage across VCCS is 12 V.
- Voltage across the CCVS is 8 V.
- 20 V source delivers 120 W.
- 10 A source delivers 200 W.
- VCCS absorbs 192 W.
- CCVS absorbs 128 W.

By going and simulating this in PSpice I got this, which is obviously a wrong simulation:

Error:

```
**** INCLUDING SCHEMATIC1.net ****
* source SDFGSDFGSDF
V_V1         N00310 0 20Vdc
I_I2         0 N00296 DC 10Adc  
X_H1    N00596 N00608 N00608 0 SCHEMATIC1_H1 
G_G1         N00296 N00596 N00296 N00310 0.8

.subckt SCHEMATIC1_H1 1 2 3 4  
H_H1         3 4 VH_H1 0.5
VH_H1         1 2 0V
.ends SCHEMATIC1_H1

**** RESUMING kkkk.cir ****
.END

ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N00296 is floating
```

[image]What I double-checked:

- Since there are multiple libraries providing the 0 symbol for the ground, I made sure SOURCE is the library providing ground.
- For the the current controlled voltage source (CCVS), I made sure the PSPice library's symbol was G.
- For the the volatage controlled voltage source (VCVS), I made sure the PSPice library's symbol was H.
- Double checked all positive and negative signs.
- Double checked all values
- Simulation settings:

  [image: List item]

**UPDATE:**

It worked after changing the circuit to the following:

[image]

Comment: F1 should be a VCCS (what is depicted on the given schematic), not a CCCS (what is in the SPICE schematic now). It should be "G" and not "F."

Comment: Right, when I change it to G, it gave me this error 
ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N00296 is floating

Comment: G's input voltage should be across \$V_{ab}\$.  Right now it's not.  Connect G- to ground, not to V1+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with this PSpice simulation?

The top-most controlled source in the circuit diagram is a *voltage* controlled current source.  But, in the simulation, you have a *current* controlled current source there instead.

Also, note that when you change to a VCVS, you must adjust the wiring so that the controlling voltage is the voltage across the voltage source.

This should be a quick fix.  After you've updated your simulation, update the question with the correct simulation.

Comment: When I switch to a VCVS, it didn't compile. Answer updated.

Comment: @georgechalhoub, I see your updated simulation and I note that you did not follow my 2nd paragraph instructions.  As you've drawn it, the 20V voltage source is disconnected from the rest of the circuit. Since this is your first time working with pspice, I understand the learning curve but carefully note that there is no path for current through the 20V voltage source.  I would like to help you but I don't want to just give you the answer.  You should reason this out yourself.

Comment: I know that you mean  G- should be connected to the ground but the thing is I thought Vab connections could be replaced by connections to the 20V source, since by KVL Vab = 20V.

Comment: thanks it worked now :). I updated my answer if members need help in similar question.